# User emails with whitespaces, fix with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I found out that within my 65.000 users, there's many who have whitespaces in their email like this:

```
"firstname@email.com "
" firstname@email.com"
" firstname@email.com "
```

This could easily be solved by php trim() function, and I would get the clean email.

It isnt possible to enter a email at the input like this anymore, but it was and therefore I have emails like this in the first 20k users.

I wonder if I could do a smart UPDATE MySQL query, that cleans (trims the emails) in one run or if i have to use some php, where i grab all the users and go through them, trim() and update the row for each 65k users?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`TRIM`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) in MySql as well:

```
update users set email = TRIM(email);
```

Comment: What a great answer! But the query fails: Duplicate entry 'email@email.com' for key 'uniq_email' - What can I do in this situation? I looked up the email and there's only one row, so I dont understand why it thinks it there is duplicate entry? Any suggestions?

Comment: @Karem `SELECT A.Email FROM Users A INNER JOIN Users B ON A.Email = TRIM(B.Email) GROUP BY A.Email HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` that will show you the duplicates

Comment: Or `select trim(email) from users group by trim(email) having count(*) > 1`

Comment: This is just perfect! Thanks to you both for the effort

Answer (score -3):

Use the `trim()` function in PHP and update all entries in your database. Be aware of PHP execution time, you may have to split up your updates in different executions.

Comment: -1 as it is a very bad advice. It is possible with a simple update statement.

Comment: Probably, since I've mostly done PHP that would be my solution. The first answer seems to solve the problem better.